# TCP echo server security

Tags: linux, networking, centos, security, tcp

I am setting up a Linux server similar to a TCP echo server and am wondering about security issues I should be concerned about.  This will be a bare bones Centos/KDE server with no additional files other than my server binary listening on a port of my choice.  Assuming I don't have any buffer overflows or similar security flaws in my server and if I configure the server to drop all non-TCP traffic on all ports except for the one my server is listening on, do I have much to worry about?  The server runs from user with execute only permissions and I use a STRONG root password.  Am I missing anything?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use xinetd to limit the number of concurrent connections otherwise it will be easy to do a DDOS on you.  xinetd also has several other useful features to strengthen things.

Can you restrict access from a certain number of hosts - if so then firewall off the rest of the world for that port.

If you are allowing external ssh access to this system, then move sshd to a non standard port and do not allow root logins.  Ideally use ssh keys instead of or with passwords.

Comment: Thank you for your input.  Initially I can't restrict the number of hosts for what I'm trying to accomplish.  I may be able to change that requirement at some point.  I did think about DDOS already and should have mentioned I plan on implementing some kind of restriction control - thanks for the xinetd recommendation.  I'll disable ssh since the server will physically be in my possession.